# Permission to execute function pg_ls_dir

Tags: postgresql

I created a monitoring account called `zabbix`. This account has the CONNECT privilege to database netbox.

I added the privileges ALL to function pg_catalog.pg_ls_dir(text).

However I still have these errors in postgresql logs:

```
2020-06-08 13:14:45 UTC ERROR:  permission denied for function pg_ls_dir
2020-06-08 13:14:45 UTC STATEMENT:  SELECT      count(*)
        FROM    pg_ls_dir('pg_xlog')
```

What I miss ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow `zabbix` role to execute this function.

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION pg_ls_dir TO zabbix;
```

Comment: I tried to add this permission today but the error appears again.

Comment: @SamuelMutel you need to grant execute on function pg_ls_dir instead of pg_ls_waldir

Comment: Indeed, for versions < PostgreSQL 10 there was no `pg_ls_waldir` function, and yes, you need to grant permission for `pg_ls_dir` instead.